# Web API returns 404 from IIS

Tags: iis, deployment, webapi

I am getting a 404 from a .net core 5.0 web app that I have deployed to a newly set up windows server. I have installed the dotnet-hosting-5.0.11-win runtime libraries on the server and installed IIS with the following settings:

[image: IIS Settings]

When I browse to it from IIS I get a 404. I gave up on the initial project and started clean with a stripped down version from the VS2019 templates. Still got the 404 :

[image: 404 Error]

Here is the project from VS2019 itself just to give you a clearer idea of what I am trying to install and run from the Windows server:

[image: VS2019 project]

Here are the publish options for the project:

[image: Publish Options]

Created a new website in IIS for this app. Here are the settings for that:

[image: IIS Website Settings]

Here are the app pool settings for the app:

[image: App pool settings]

Here is the web.config file for the app:

[image: Web.Config]

Enabled directory browsing based on other posts I read:

Here is a snapshot of the logs file on the server:

[image: Server Log Files]

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you run a report to rule out common issues? https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: Go to your Application Pool list, select your created App Pool, and hit "Basic Settings". From there, you need to set .NET CLR Version is set to "No Managed Code". This tells IIS not to kick off the .NET Framework pipeline for your .NET Core app.

Comment: I have figured it out.

Comment: Need to add this to the web.config : <environmentVariables>
     <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
   </environmentVariables>